# Spring batch using java annotations java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create properties without meta data

Tags: spring-batch

1. Trying to Automapping FieldSets to Domain Objects using java anotations only in project
2. Failing at the following :

   `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.mapFieldSet` (line 184) at following line (line 187) :

   ```
   binder.bind(new MutablePropertyValues(getBeanProperties(copy, fs.getProperties())));
   @Override
   public Properties getProperties() {
       if (names == null) {
           throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot create properties without meta data");
       }
   ```

   Note: I did not specify names as I am trying to Automap.
3. Following is my code :

   ```
   @Bean
       public LineMapper<Partner> lineMapper() {
           DefaultLineMapper<Partner> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<Partner>();
           DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
           BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Partner> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Partner>(); 
           fieldSetMapper.setBeanFactory(getApplicationContext()); 
           fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(Partner.class);
           lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
           lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
           return lineMapper;
       }
   ```
4. Exact stack trace

   Exit-Descr. : `org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 1 in resource=[class path resource [partner-import.csv]], input=[Mustermann,Max,dahiya.naveen@gmail.com,m]`

   Caused by: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create properties without meta data
   at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DefaultFieldSet.getProperties(DefaultFieldSet.java:745)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to set [likeTokenizer.setNames()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/AbstractLineTokenizer.html#setNames-java.lang.String:A-) because you are working with names (the names of your `Partner` properties)

Comment: I am trying to automap, refer 6.6.2.7. Automapping FieldSets to Domain Objects from batch-ref

I should not be required to specify names.

Comment: Do you have header names into csv file?

Comment: yes, I have first record as exact column names in partner bean.

Comment: I don't have headers, how but I get same error @Luca Basso Ricci